# How to open work item query result in microsoft excel from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

Hi I am trying to open Work item query results in microsoft excel but getting an error **"TF208093 you cannot use work item query to generate reports in excel on this server because it is not configured for reporting"**

Below are the steps which I performed

```
1. Installed excel extension from marketplace on Azure DevOps
2. Installed Visual Studio 2017
3. Installed Team Foundation Server Integration 2017
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you Azure DevOps in the cloud or Azure DevOps Server (TFS)?

Comment: export to csv then open in excel :D    what is the azure devops version and the excel version that you are using?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk and leo I am using azure devops 2019 cloud and excel version is 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the "open work item query result in microsoft excel" through the excel extension with below process:

1. Click the “Open in Excel” in Query Results after I installed the Excel extension for my organization:

[image]

2. Click the “Open TfsProtocolHandler.exe” button in popup dialog

[image]

3. Now we can see it in Excel opened automatically:

[image]

The only difference between my process and yours is that i didn't install **Team Foundation Server Integration 2017** (I have Visual Studio 2017 on my computer), you can try to uninstall it and do the process again see if we can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @YS5079 let me try this out and let you know

Comment: Hey @YS5079 I have tried but still same error let me check again if there any administrative restriction while accessing.

Comment: I noticed that you have not save the current query when you click the "Open in Excel"? Please try save the query first and then "Open in Excel".

Answer (score 1):

Your error very similar to the error with the reports generation. Azure DevOps Service does not support Reports:

[image]

Try to open your query directly from Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2019 appears to not be installing the needed component (maybe only under certain workloads?).

Whether have VS 2019 or not, this download should solve the issue: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#azure-devops-office-integration-2019

Note: this isn't quite a direct answer to the question, since the questioner does have the `TfsProtocolHandler.exe`, rather this answer is a fix for "nothing happens when I click 'Open in Excel'"